# join with prefix string

Tags: mysql, join, concatenation

Have two MYSQL tables need them to join. Orders table has conso column as primary key

CONSO TABLE

```
CONSO(p_key)     | sku      |Tally_Name
-------------------------
f|HP3001         | HP3001   |Computer_Accessory
f|XP3001         | XP3001   |XPRO
f|YP3001         | YP3001   |YPRO
a|HP3001         | HP3001   |Computer_Accessory
a|XP3001         | XP3001   |XPRO
a|YP3001         | YP3001   |Computer_Accessory
```

ORDER TABLE

```
f|sku
-----
HP3001
YP3001
XP3001
XP3001
Hp3001
```

Result expected is to concat with prefixstring 'f|` and join

concat ('f|',order.`f|sku`)= conso.conso

```
f|sku   | Tally_Name
--------------------
HP3001  |Computer_Accessory
YP3001  |YPRO
XP3001  |XPRO
XP3001  |XPRO
Hp3001  |Computer_Accessory
```

Comment: So whats the problem? it seems you have the where condition already

Comment: tried, this is not working.

Comment: Did you try it without a capital letter? I think its case sensitive.

Comment: try selecting concat ('f|',order.f|sku) from order table, what does it return?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM `order`,`conso` WHERE concat (`f|`,order.`f|sku`) = conso.conso`  this is what I tried

Comment: No, i mean try this query: select concat (f|,order.f|sku) from order . what do you get?